# Need to scroll to find yourself in leaderboard in mobile version

Tags: support, mobile-web, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

If I go to the Winter Bash leaderboard on the mobile version, I don't come on the top:

[image]

But the same if I do on the desktop; I come on the top with my leaderboard position. Above the number one position. Which adds unnecessary scrolling necessity while using a mobile browser. I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: What mobile phone and operating system, incl. version?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Realme X2 pro, Android 11

Comment: ...It looks like you're not logged in to the Winter Bash site on your phone, which would explain why you're not being shown above the other leaderboard rankings there :P

Comment: @V2Blast didn't realise that till you pointed to out. So I didn't specifically login on WB page when I saw this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just posting this as an answer since it identifies the cause of the issue:

It looks like you're not logged in to the Winter Bash site on your phone, which would explain why you're not being shown above the other leaderboard rankings there. If you log in on the Winter Bash site, you should see your username displayed above the full leaderboard for each site.